# How to refactor method with RxJS operators?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to use the RxJS `BehaviorSubject` object to write to `searchFruit`  the values ​​that I get when deleting / adding / when writing a new string.

```js
export class ChipsAutocompleteExample {
  visible = true;
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;

  fruitCtrl = FormControl;
  filteredFruits: Observable < string[] > ;
  fruits: string[] = ['Lemon'];
  allFruits: string[] = ['Apple', 'Lemon', 'Lime', 'Orange', 'Strawberry'];

  searchFruit = new BehaviorSubject < List[] > (this.parentFormGroup.get('fruitCtrl').value);

  @Input() parentFormGroup: FormGroup;

  @ViewChild('fruitInput', {
    static: false
  }) fruitInput: ElementRef < HTMLInputElement > ;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createControlForAutocomplete();
    this.listeningControls();

  }


  listeningControls(): void {
    this.filteredFruits = this.fruitCtrl.pipe(
      startWith(this.parentFormGroup.get('fruitCtrl').value),
      map((fruit: string | null) => fruit ? this._filter(fruit, 'fruit') : this.allFruits.slice()),
      map(fruits => fruits.filter(fruit => !this.fruits.includes(fruit))),
    );
  }

  createControlForAutocomplete(): void {
    this.fruitCtrl = this.fb.control('');
  }


  remove(value: string, ctrlName: string): void {
    const control = this.parentFormGroup.get(ctrlName);
    const index = control.value.indexOf(value);

    if (index > -1) {
      const temp = [...control.value];
      temp.splice(index, 1);
      control.setValue([...temp]);
    }
  }

  selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent, ctrlName: 'fruit'): void {
    const control = this.parentFormGroup.get(ctrlName);
    const temp = [...control.value, event.option.value];
    control.setValue(temp);
    (this[ctrlName + 'Input'] as ElementRef < HTMLInputElement > ).nativeElement.value = '';
  }
}

private _filter(value: string, ctrlName: 'fruit'): string[] {
  const currentControl = this[ctrlName];
  const selectedItems = this.parentFormGroup.get(ctrlName).value;

  if (!value) {
    return currentControl.slice();
  }


  currentControl.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().includes(value));

  return currentControl.filter(item => {
    return item !== value && !selectedItems.includes(item);
  });

}
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-chip-list #chipFruitList aria-label="Fruit selection">
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{fruit}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input placeholder="New fruit..." #fruitInput [formControl]="fruitCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [matChipInputFor]="chipFruitList">
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event, 'fruit')">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
      {{fruit}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
   
   let requests:[] = [];
   getPipeRequest(param: string){
     return this.getItems(request, [param]).pipe(
      map((resp: Array<any>) => {
        const newItems = this.transformItems(resp);
        return newItems;
      }),
    );
   }
   requests.push(this.getPipeRequest('RECEIVED'));
   requests.push(this.getPipeRequest('NEW'));
   
    forkJoin(...requests).subscribe(resp => {
      let items: any[] = [];
      resp.forEach(item => {
        items.unshift(item);
      });
      items.forEach(item => {
        this.changeStatusForItem.push(item);
      });
    });
```

Comment: sorry, I didn`t specify that `item` is of type object. so I get an error `Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '{}'`

Answer (score 0):

A neater way to merge arrays returned in the `subscribe` function is using [spread operator syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const pipe1$ = this.getItems(request, ['RECEIVED']).pipe(
      map((resp: Array<any>) => {
        const newItems = this.transformItems(resp);
        return newItems;
      }),
    );
const pipe2 = this.getItems(request, ['NEW']).pipe(
      map((resp: Array<any>) => {
        const newItems = this.transformItems(resp);
        return newItems;
      }),
    );
// Changed your merged statements
forkJoin(pipe1$, pipe2$).subscribe([data1, data2] => {
      this.changeStatusForItem.push(...data1, ...data2)
}
```

Spread operator example:

```
const a = [1,2]
const b = [3,4]
const c = [5,6]

a.push(...b, ...c)
console.log(a) // return [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: I`m not obvious your decision. can you write in more detail?

Comment: I seeing you trying to merged the return data to `changeStatusForItem` array, than use spread operator syntax, updated my answer